# wix wants an assembly manifest - I have one

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I have created a C# CustomActions project to use in wix to create an installer. All I have is the sample project and a sample wix project that references it. And I created an app.manifest in the C# project.

[Example simple program](https://www.dropbox.com/s/auanpay6eh8ne85/WixTest.zip?dl=0)

What I get is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SetupProject1, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>      C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe -dDebug -d"DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\\" -dSolutionDir=C:\src\WixTest\ -dSolutionExt=.sln -dSolutionFileName=WixTest.sln -dSolutionName=WixTest -dSolutionPath=C:\src\WixTest\WixTest.sln -dConfiguration=Debug -dOutDir=bin\Debug\ -dPlatform=x86 -dProjectDir=C:\src\SetupProject1\ -dProjectExt=.wixproj -dProjectFileName=SetupProject1.wixproj -dProjectName=SetupProject1 -dProjectPath=C:\src\SetupProject1\SetupProject1.wixproj -dTargetDir=C:\src\SetupProject1\bin\Debug\ -dTargetExt=.msi -dTargetFileName=SetupProject1.msi -dTargetName=SetupProject1 -dTargetPath=C:\src\SetupProject1\bin\Debug\SetupProject1.msi -out obj\Debug\ -arch x86 -ext ..\WixTest\bin\Debug\WixTest.CA.dll Product.wxs
1>candle.exe(0,0): error CNDL0144: The extension '..\WixTest\bin\Debug\WixTest.CA.dll' could not be loaded because of the following reason: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\src\WixTest\bin\Debug\WixTest.CA.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
1>Done building project "SetupProject1.wixproj" -- FAILED.
1>
```

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Any idea what else I need to do?

Comment: If you are on a virtual it could be a missing runtime. Or it could be a path issue - a folder resolution issue.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Not on a virtual and I've triple checked everything. Could you take a look please? I put the sample program up in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I had a look - please try this:

1. Please remove the reference to **`WixTestCA`**, leave **`WixTest`** in there. You don't need a direct reference to the WixTestCA file. You need a project reference instead.
2. Add your company name or something (anything will do) to the attribute **`Manufacturer`**.
3. Add **`After='InstallInitialize'`** to the Custom element to indicate scheduling inside the InstallExecuteSequence for the custom action in question.

Here are the snippets with injected changes:

The **`Product element`**:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Add Company Name here" UpgradeCode="ADD-VALID-GUID-HERE">
```

The **`Custom element`** (custom action):

```
<Custom Action='LicenseInfoCustomAction' After='InstallInitialize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
```